# The method given() is undefined for the type - http://rest-assured.io/

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest-assured

I am trying to write a unit test for a web service in Java using io-rest-assured. Looks like so much have changed since I last used it. I am getting the error The `method given() is undefined for the type`. I have imported almost all the required jars as appears to me. Any suggestions as what am I missing?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.RequestPostProcessor;
import io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.*;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;

public class ProxyIntegrationTest_RA extends MockControllerIntegrationTest{

    private static final String REQUEST_MAPPING = "/xy/v1/fax";

    @Test
    public void testGetServices_success() throws Exception {
        final String niv = "1234567890";

        given().
            param("store","0123").
        when().
            get(REQUEST_MAPPING + "/vehicles/{niv}/serviceHistory", niv).
        then().
            statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

given(), when(), then() none is recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a static import for the static `given()` method :

```
    import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.given;
```

Or import the class, and call the static method as usual :

```
    import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers;
```

...

```
    RestAssuredMatchers.given().
        param("store","0123").
    when().
        get(REQUEST_MAPPING + "/vehicles/{niv}/serviceHistory", niv).
    then().
        statusCode(200);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue as apun, but Arnaud's answer didn't fix the error.

For me, adding this import worked:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but worked with the below line

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*
```

Answer (score 0):

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).